# Trying to grow a partition fails, resize2fs keeps asking to run e2fsck first

Tags: partition, gparted, xubuntu, resize2fs

I used Gparted first to place some free space directly to the right of my xubuntu installation on /dev/sda4, but it fails to grow the partition to include the free space.

I then tried these below commands in the terminal. I am using a usb version of fedora to resize my partition /dev/sda4, which contians my xubuntu installation. Below you can see commands I have tried many times, and receive the same result each time.

**EDIT:** I also run 'sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sda4' before 'resize2fs', but receive the same errors.

```
[liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ sudo resize2fs -p /dev/sda4
resize2fs 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
Please run 'e2fsck -f /dev/sda4' first.
```

I run the command e2fsck, but everything seems to pass.

```
[liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sda4
e2fsck 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Xubuntu: 382621/1310720 files (0.6% non-contiguous), 4981944/5242880 blocks
```

I tried seeing if there was anything suspicious by running dumpe2fs , but I can't tell.

```
[liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda4
dumpe2fs 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
Filesystem volume name:   Xubuntu
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem UUID:          77fa52e3-9d25-486f-ab3b-cf1e8532cd86
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              1310720
Block count:              5242880
Reserved block count:     262144
Free blocks:              260936
Free inodes:              928099
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Group descriptor size:    64
Reserved GDT blocks:      1024
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Thu Nov 12 06:26:28 2020
Last mount time:          Wed Dec 16 20:04:03 2020
Last write time:          Wed Dec 16 16:59:53 2020
Mount count:              0
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Wed Dec 16 16:59:53 2020
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          104 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      e69bf846-11fc-4b21-8be9-a611becafcda
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Checksum type:            crc32c
Checksum:                 0x8542198c
Journal features:         journal_incompat_revoke journal_64bit journal_checksum_v3
Journal size:             128M
Journal length:           32768
Journal sequence:         0x002fe7a6
Journal start:            0
Journal checksum type:    crc32c
Journal checksum:         0x123373ce
```

Gparted gave this log:

```
GParted 1.1.0

configuration --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

libparted 3.3

========================================

Device: /dev/sda
Model:  ATA ST750LM022 HN-M7
Serial: 
Sector size:    512
Total sectors:  1465149168
 
Heads:  255
Sectors/track:  2
Cylinders:  2872841
 
Partition table:    gpt
 
Partition   Type    Start   End Flags   Partition Name  File System Label   Mount Point
/dev/sda1   Primary 2048    2099199 boot, esp   EFI System Partition    fat32   EFI BOOT    
/dev/sda2   Primary 2099200 4196351 bios_grub   BIOS Boot   unknown     
/dev/sda3   Primary 4196352 46139391    swap    Swap    linux-swap      
/dev/sda4   Primary 46139392    300410879       Xubuntu ext4    Xubuntu 
/dev/sda5   Primary 300410880   342353919       Ubuntu Gnome    ext4    Ubuntu Gnome    
/dev/sda6   Primary 342353920   426231807       Mac OS  ext4    Mac OS  
/dev/sda7   Primary 426240000   468183039       Lubuntu ext4    Lubuntu 
/dev/sda8   Primary 468183040   510126079       Kubuntu ext4    Kubuntu 
/dev/sda9   Primary 510126080   520611839       LXDE    ext4    LXDE    
/dev/sda10  Primary 520611840   562554879       Fedora  ext4    Fedora  
/dev/sda11  Primary 562554880   583526399       Windows ext4    Windows 
/dev/sda12  Primary 583526400   583731199           ext4        
/dev/sda13  Primary 583731200   583935999           ext4        
/dev/sda14  Primary 583936000   584140799           ext4        
/dev/sda15  Primary 584140800   584345599           ext4        
/dev/sda16  Primary 584345600   626288639       Work    ext4    /Work   
/dev/sda17  Primary 626288640   1465147391      Storage ext4    /Storage    
========================================

Device: /dev/sdb
Model:  Kingston DT 101 II
Serial: 
Sector size:    512
Total sectors:  31252024
 
Heads:  255
Sectors/track:  2
Cylinders:  61278
 
Partition table:    none
 
Partition   Type    Start   End Flags   Partition Name  File System Label   Mount Point
/dev/sdb    Unpartitioned   0   31252023            iso9660 Fedora-WS-Live-33-1-2   
========================================

Check and repair file system (ext4) on /dev/sda4  00:00:19    ( ERROR )
        
calibrate /dev/sda4  00:00:03    ( SUCCESS )
        
path: /dev/sda4 (partition)
start: 46139392
end: 300410879
size: 254271488 (121.25 GiB)
check file system on /dev/sda4 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:00:16    ( SUCCESS )
        
e2fsck -f -y -v -C 0 '/dev/sda4'  00:00:16    ( SUCCESS )
        
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

382621 inodes used (29.19%, out of 1310720)
1606 non-contiguous files (0.4%)
584 non-contiguous directories (0.2%)
# of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
Extent depth histogram: 338128/467
4981944 blocks used (95.02%, out of 5242880)
0 bad blocks
1 large file

282523 regular files
54354 directories
9 character device files
0 block device files
0 fifos
31938 links
45684 symbolic links (43967 fast symbolic links)
42 sockets
------------
414550 files
e2fsck 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
grow file system to fill the partition  00:00:00    ( ERROR )
        
resize2fs -p '/dev/sda4'  00:00:00    ( ERROR )
        
resize2fs 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
Please run 'e2fsck -f /dev/sda4' first.
```

Comment: What happens when you run `e2fsck -f /dev/sda4` first, and then retry the `resize2fs -p /dev/sda4`? Your question seems to suggest that you've run the `e2fsck` but not reattempted the resize.

Comment: Same error. I've run e2fsck -f /dev/sda4 several times before the inputs i posted

Comment: Your first sentence says you can't grow the partition. Until you've done that there's no point using either `e2fsck` or `resize2fs`

Comment: How do you get more information about why the partition can't grow?

Comment: You do not have any free space to grow `/dev/sda4`.  Look at the output of `gparted`.  No free space between `/dev/sda4` and `/dev/sda5`.